# Tkinter animation becomes unresponsive and crashes unless calling root.update() on each frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to play some simple animations on a window. It's my first time using Tkinter, so I set a call to root.update() at each frame to ensure that it gets shown on screen (the frame rate was a bit erratic otherwise). I have now learned that this is very bad practice, and tried to either remove it completely, or substitute it with a call to root.update_idletasks(). The weird thing is that when I do that, the window becomes unresponsive and eventually crashes.

I tried stripping my code down to its bare minimum (shown below), but the problem still persists.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class Application():
    def __init__(self):
        # WINDOW SETUP
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('512x512')
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.Annihilation)

        self.screen = ttk.Label(self.root)
        self.screen.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

        # CALL THE ANIMATION FUNCTION
        self.state = 'Idle'
        self.Animation(self.state, [self.Idle1, self.Idle2], 500)

        self.root.mainloop()


    # ANIMATION FUNCTION
    def Animation(self, State, framelist, frameduration):
        for i in range(len(framelist)):
            if self.state == State:
                frame = framelist[i]()
                self.screen.configure(image = frame)
                self.root.update() # THIS IS THE LINE I WANT TO REMOVE
                self.root.after(frameduration)          
            else:
                return

        self.Animation(State, framelist, frameduration)

    # LIST OF IMAGES
    def Idle1(self):
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Image1.tif').resize((512, 512)))
    def Idle2(self):
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Image2.tif').resize((512, 512)))


    def Annihilation(self):
        self.root.eval('::ttk::CancelRepeat')
        self.state = 'Quitting'
        self.root.destroy()

Application()
```

This smells of "There's a much bigger mistake in your code that your first mistake is accidentally keeping at bay", but I'm out of ideas and I haven't been able to Google this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use for loop in Animation and not run Animation in Animation which create recursion. It make take long time and then it blocks `mainloop()` which can't events from system, sends events to widgets, redraw widgets, run function assigned with `after()`, etc. and you have to use `update()` to give some time mainloop to make it all. You should use `after` to run Animation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should't use `for` loop which can take some time and make no sens without some time between frames. Don't run `Animation` in `Animation` because it create recursion which you don't need. Use `after(time, Animation)`

I use `self.current_frame` to keep information which frame to display. `Animation`displays only one frame, change value in `self.current_frame` and use `after()` to run it again - it replaces `for` loop. It also replaces recursion.

You could also load image only once and keep images on list instead of names of functions
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image

```
class Application():

    def __init__(self):

        # WINDOW SETUP
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('512x512')
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.annihilation)

        self.screen = ttk.Label(self.root)
        self.screen.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

        # CALL THE ANIMATION FUNCTION
        self.state = 'Idle'

        self.current_frame = 0
        self.animation(self.state, [self.idle1, self.idle2], 500)

        self.root.mainloop()


    # ANIMATION FUNCTION
    def animation(self, State, framelist, frameduration):
        if state == self.state:
            # change image
            self.frame = framelist[self.current_frame]()
            self.screen.configure(image=self.frame)

            # get next frame (or first frame)
            self.current_frame = (self.current_frame+1) % len(framelist)

        # run again after 'frameduration' milliseconds
        self.root.after(frameduration, self.animation, State, framelist, frameduration)


    # LIST OF IMAGES
    def idle1(self):
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Image1.tif').resize((512, 512)))

    def idle2(self):
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Image2.tif').resize((512, 512)))


    def annihilation(self):
        self.root.eval('::ttk::CancelRepeat')
        self.state = 'Quitting'
        self.root.destroy()

Application()
```

I changed names to lower case because of [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did try something similar to this in order to avoid calling Animation() so many times, but there are some problems when adding different animations: How do I tell the program to stop the current animation at once to instantaneously start the other? If I don't do that, the frames get mixed up.

Also, while I agree that this sort of solution would be best for my case, would you mind shedding some light into why my current code seems to require the call to .update() ? It might help someone and I'm curious.

Comment: the main element in every GUI (and game) is event loop (mainloop). it runs loop which gets key/mouse events from system, sends events to widgets, update values in widget, starts functions when you press button, runs function added by after(), and it draws and redraw widgets in window. If you run long-running function (ie. `while True` or `time.sleep()` or recursion) then it doesn't go back to mainloop and it can't redraw widgets and you see frozen GUI.

Comment: Your Animation runs again Aniamation at the end (which will run Aniamation at the end, etc.) so it never ends running and it never go back to mainloop and it can't redraw widgets. If you run `root.update()` then it run one "event loop" which can get events from system, update widgets and redraw them.

Comment: Ooooh I see! Okay, that makes sense now. I have used your method and everything works much better now (it's way more responsive). Thanks for your time!

Comment: to control after you can use two methods or both. (1) use variable `running` to stop animation -`if running: after(...)`. At start set `running=True` and to stop it with `running=False`. It will stop after showing next frame so you can put all code in animation inside `if running`. (2) `after()` puts function on list and mainloop() will run it later but it also gives you ID of this job - `job_id = after()` and you can remove it `after_cancel(joib_id)` but if function is running in this moment then you ma still need first version so you can use both methods at the same time.

Comment: I took your animation and created widget `AnimatedLabel`. Example use it to display 3 animated labels at the same time which runs animation with different speed. [python-examples/tkinter/animated-label](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/animated-label)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the effort! Instead of a `running` variable, I set a `state` variable, which has the advantage of allowing me to do more complex stuff like "If you click A while in state X, then play animation 3 and switch to state Y. Else, play animation 2 and switch to state X". Still, I will borrow some useful stuff from your file :P